# Insertion performance from one table to other sql server

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert

Please help in below performance issue.

I have a table A with 920 Million rows(67GB Table size) and table A doesn't have any index or keys.

Now i want to copy entire table A to table B it's located in some other database with in same instance and i followed below ways to accomplish this task.

Option 1:

I used `select * into db..table B` and it takes 70 minutes of time.

Option 2:

Tried with "**Insert with select statement**" along with TABLOCK to enable minimal logging(But both of my databases are in simple recovery model) and it also took same time like option 1.

Option 3:

Thinking to use batch wise insertion 10 million once.

Table A and table B bot have any index, keys.

Query:

```
insert into TableB with(TABLOCK)
select 
AUTO_POLICY_NUMBER,
HOME_POLICY_NUMBER,
TRANSACTION_MM,
TRANSACTION_DD,
TRANSACTION_YY,
ANTICIPATION_MM,
ANTICIPATION_DD,
ANTICIPATION_YY,
STATUS_MM     ,
STATUS_DD     ,
STATUS_YY     ,
PRESENT_STATUS,
PRIOR_STATUS  ,
LoadDate              ,
RecordId              ,
AuditTableLoadId      ,
CopybookId   
 From TableA
```

can any one of you suggest other options to make my data load smooth(less time).

Note:- My server has 16GB of RAM with Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz, 2593 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s).

Thank you!

Comment: The important spec is the *disks*, not the CPU or RAM. You're trying to move 67GB of data on the same disk or array. Table hints won't make the disks go faster. You're moving data at 15MB/sec now, which means 45MB/sec actual IO at least (15MB/s data read, 15MB/s data write, 15 log write at least)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you!. Target is in simple recovery model so can i give a try with by changing bulk recovery model? But in production can not able to use Bulk logged due to the need of point in time. :)

Comment: Simple is the same as `bulk logging all the time`. `Bulk logged` is `bulk logging only for bulk operations`. What about the *disks* though?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos we are using HDD in dev server with RAID 5.

Comment: RAID 5 is not a speed measurement. Did you check Task Manager or Performance Monitor while performing this copy? How busy are the disks? Do you see a long IO queue?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos unfortunetly no. But let me check that and come back to you.

Comment: One of the options that can slightly increase the perfomance is using bcp utility.

Comment: @ArtemIgnatovich But I have to do table to table copy. BCP works in that case?

Comment: @TharunkumarReddy dont think I correctly understand the struggle. Let me clarify a  bit. 1) BCP copies content of TableA to a data file. 2) Data file is read from the db containing TableB and then TableB is populated from that data file.
The main benefit of this approach - it helps to skip a lot of stuff happening in the database engine internally.

Note: this approach will not give much if query hits the Disk I/O or Network I/O cap.

Comment: @ArtemIgnatovich Thank you will try this and validate performance.